# How to detect if number have 1 at the end?

Tags: javascript, numbers

How to detect numbers likie: 21, 31, 41, 101, I've try this:

```
number & 1 == 1
```

but it return true for numbers that have first bit set to 1 like 23, 33, 43, or 103.

Comment: Using RegEx `/1$/.test('' + number)`

Comment: Using [`endsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) in latest envs `('' + number).endsWith('1')`

Comment: May be `"101".split('').pop()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the last number like:
                  (number % 10)
and then compare it.

Comment: console.log((number % 10) == 1);

Answer (score 0):

All those numbers *do* have `1` at the end - in binary! If you want to look at the decimal representation, do so explicitly:

```
number.toString(10).endsWith('1')
number % 10 == 1
```

(admittedly, base 10 is the default for stringification, so `String(number).endsWith` or `/1$/.test(number)` work as well)

Answer (score -2):

You can convert the number to string and use lastindexof to compare with the length of the string

Like this :

```js
var myNumber = 12011;
var strMyNumber = myNumber.toString();
if (strMyNumber.lastIndexOf('1') === (strMyNumber.length - 1))
 alert('end with 1');
else
   alert('Not end with 1');
```

Comment: Neat, the empty string (`""`) ends with `1`.